# Converter activity em fragments

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment, android-activity

Olá, eu estou precisando muito de ajuda, eu estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação para o meu TCC, eu já montei a maior parte das funcionalidades e agora que fui mexer com a parte visual tive problemas, eu montei tudo em activitys, mas agora queria usar os TabsLayouts, que utilizam fragments pelo que eu entendi, já montei alguns exemplos de TabsLayouts com fragments, mas eu não consigo transportar as funções que eu tinha criado nas Activitys para esses Fragments, alguem sabe como fazer isso??? Agradeço desde já a ajuda !!!

### Exemplo de Activity

```
public class morador extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView txt_exibe_nome, txt_exibe_idade, txt_exibe_apto,txt_exibe_bloco;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_morador);
//instanciando onde vai exibir os dados
    txt_exibe_nome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_exibe_nome);
    txt_exibe_idade = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_exibe_idade);
    txt_exibe_apto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_exibe_apto);
    txt_exibe_bloco = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_exibe_bloco);

    if(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).isLoggedIn()){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, login.class));
    }

    txt_exibe_nome.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).exibeMoradorNome());
    txt_exibe_idade.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).exibeMoradoridade());
    txt_exibe_apto.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).exibeMoradorApto());
    txt_exibe_bloco.setText(SharedPrefManager.getInstance(this).exibeMoradorBloco());
  }
}
```

### Fragment onde quero jogar esse codigo

```
public class Fragment_perfil extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);
 }

}
```

### FragmentAdapter

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private String[] mTab;
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, String[] mTab) {
    super(fm);
    this.mTab = mTab;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return new Fragment_perfil();
        case 1:
            return new Fragment_perfil();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.mTab.length;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return this.mTab[position];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu Fragment deve ficar mais ou menos assim

```
public class Fragment_perfil extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment {
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_perfil, container, false);
    // Copiar código do OnCreate após o setContentView
    // Trocar os findViewById por rootView.findViewById
    // Trocar this por getActivity()
    return rootView;
 }

}
```

OBS: Estou assumindo que você vai usar no Fragment o mesmo layout da Activity.

Comment: Esse codigo vai retornar do Fragment os dados pra Activity correto ???

Comment: Não entendi a pergunta. Retornar o que?

Comment: Agradeço pela resposta deixada aqui, @MárcioOliveira! Sua explicação foi mais do que suficiente para compreender a situação e resolver o problema e poderia ter sido aceita tranquilamente.